# Imshow with pixels proportional to ticks

Tags: matplotlib, imshow

I have an image below which has non-uniformly spaced `xticks` and `yticks` (0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 1). I'd like to make the grid proportional to the interval of the corresponding tick. So, in this example, I'd like to make the last two columns and rows to be half their current width/height. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: You'll need to create the plot with `plt.pcolor` instead of with `plt.imshow`. You might want to reread [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!